# what's wrong here ? while (temp->ptr_Next != NULL) fails, if (temp->ptr_Next == NULL) works

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I've been making a doubly linked list and the while statements are going a bit wonky. I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I'm not seeing it. Can anyone help?

This is working (Embarcadero RAD studio 11.1 - C++ Builder - Classic compiler (not Clang))

```
TDoubleLinkedNode* __fastcall TDoubleLinkedList::CreateNode ( int                ID
                                                            , UnicodeString      Name
                                                            )

{
    // use "malloc" (or "new") to create the node in the heap
    // it won't be deleted automatically when the function goes out of scope
    // return the pointer to the structure
    // let the calling function set PriorNode & NextNode
    struct TDoubleLinkedNode* ReturnNode = (struct TDoubleLinkedNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct TDoubleLinkedNode));
    ReturnNode->ID            = ID;
    ReturnNode->Name          = Name;
    ReturnNode->ptr_PriorNode = NULL;
    ReturnNode->ptr_NextNode  = NULL;
    return ReturnNode;
}
void __fastcall TDoubleLinkedList::Add_ToEnd ( int                ID
                                                 , UnicodeString      Name
                                                 )
    {
       struct TDoubleLinkedNode* newNode     = CreateNode(ID,Name);
       if(this->IsEmpty)
       {
          // Head Pointer has not been initialised. Set as newNode
          this->FHeadNode = newNode;
          // This is the first Record. 
          newNode->ptr_PriorNode = NULL;
          newNode->ptr_NextNode  = NULL;
          return;
       }
       else
       {
          struct TDoubleLinkedNode* oldHeadNode = this->FHeadNode;
          struct TDoubleLinkedNode* tempNode    = this->FHeadNode;
          do   // keep iterating until a break statement is triggered
          {
             if (tempNode->ptr_NextNode == NULL)   // terminate the do while statement
             {
                break;
             }
             tempNode = tempNode->ptr_NextNode;    // Move to the "Next" record
          }
          while (true);   // always repeat...
          tempNode->ptr_NextNode = newNode;
          newNode->ptr_PriorNode = tempNode;
          newNode->ptr_NextNode  = NULL;
       }
    }
```

However, if I replace

```
do 
{
   if (tempNode->ptr_NextNode == NULL)break;
}
while (true);
```

with

```
while (tempNode->ptr_NextNode != NULL)
{
    tempNode = tempNode->ptr_NextNode ;
}
```

the while statement does not break when `tempNode->ptr_NextNode == NULL` resulting in tempNode being set to NULL making the `tempNode->ptr_NextNode = newNode` that follows fail (Since you can't assign data to a non existent object).

I have been stepping through and the while is definitely running when tempNode->ptr_NextNode == NULL , when my understanding is it shouldn't??

I'm sure this isn't the only area that's messed up (there's quite a few while statements).
I'm adding 6 test records and only able to retrieve 5! so it's obvious something is up. If you can shed some light on what I'm not understanding I'd be grateful

thanks, J

Comment: Well, for starters, DON'T use `malloc()`/`free()`, use `new`/`delete` instead, especially since `TDoubleLinkedNode` contains a member that is a class type (`Name`). A better solution is to use `std::list` and let it handle the linked-list for you.

Comment: Still digesting, but a quick note: In C++ don't have a `CreateNode` function. Use `new` and make a smarter `TDoubleLinkedNode` constructor.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with the `while` loop you propose, though it would be more idiomatic to compare with `nullptr` than with `NULL`.  If your code is not behaviing as you expect, then we would like to see a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `// use "malloc"` -- And when `TDoubleLinkedNode` contains a `std::string` or similar non-POD, boom goes your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the `TDoubleLinkedNode::Name` member is clearly a non-POD class type (it is being assigned a `UnicodeString` object)

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- You're right, didn't see it at first. Just made a general comment about usage of `malloc`.  So the program as it is now, is totally busted because of the usage of `malloc`.

Comment: @JamesM your `while` loop code is fine (though coded oddly, and inefficiently). Chances are, you are invoking undefined/illegal behavior elsewhere in the code (such as when assigning the `Name` parameter to the `ReturnNode->Name` member before it was initialized properly, due to your use of `malloc()`), and that is likely affecting the `while` loop as a *side effect*.

Comment: @OP -- This all begs the question -- where did you get the idea to use `malloc` to begin with?  If you look through countless *good* books on C++, you will not (or shouldn't) see the usage of `malloc` to create objects.  The most obvious way to pick up the `malloc` "habit" is if you picked this up from reading an example meant for `C`, and/or in general learning from `C` examples/books.  As you can see, this is not a safe habit to pick up, as your example is broken because of it.

Comment: not only should you not be using `malloc` you should be using `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` - naked `new` calls are pretty bad too as they lead to leaks or dangling pointers

Comment: just an FYI : use of malloc was in a C linked list example I found. It had "plain Old Data" (POD) included (just an int). I was intending to convert the struct to a class shortly as I wanted to add some getters and setters... I will convert to new and delete before I make the conversion.

Comment: @pm100 "*you should be using `unique_ptr` and `make_unique`*" - ideally, yes. But, the OP is using C++Builder's "classic" compiler, which is NOT a compliant C++11 compiler, it only has a [small subset of C++11 features](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B11_Features_in_the_Classic_Compiler), which does not include `unique_ptr` (it does have `auto_ptr`, though).

Comment: @RemyLebeau - missed that. OP - you should be using a *modern* c++ compiler

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used CBuilder for some 20 years, but if what you say is exactly what happens, if replacing that 'do while' loop to that 'while' changes the behavior, and you can clearly see that crazy thing occurring when you are stepping through it, it also seems illogical to me.

I don't know how it is now, but there in the beginning of the century, since C++ Builder has a lot of complicated links with Object Pascal libraries, it was not so uncommon to reach very strange situations, with crazy things happening in debug. What used to help was to do a "rebuild all", possibly removing all temporary files I could find in the project.

Maybe it helps.

And I also support our colleagues' comments regarding updating your code to use more appropriate C++ alternatives, much simpler and efficient ones, if possible (I know sometimes you can be working on legacy software which may not be easy to update).

And it is actually also very likely you are seen undefined behavior due to corrupted content, as people also said in comments. That only you can determine.

**Update**: I've just seeing the other answer here just posted by Remy Lebeau, and I would like to add he is right regarding the bad use of malloc. Searching google I see that UnicodeString seems to be an object from Object Pascal, is it? Really seems a non-POD and you will run into trouble anyway, don't use malloc for C++ objects.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. By way of feedback :
* Use of new instead of (my first and only) malloc didn't fix it
* clean and build didn't fix it
* I will take a look at std::List , thanks for this shout out
* i will start using nullptr
* i think I tried unique_ptr on some JSON stuff recently, i seem to remember it didn't compile. I think I concluded it maybe needs the clang compiler (I'm still on classic for now).
* Only using "do (if (NULL)break ;}while(true);" has all 6 items being listed now (so it looks like it's working)

Comment: Very crazy thing. Yes, it may always be a bug in your compiler, but I think it is much more likely you are facing undefined behaviour because of lost or corrupted pointers. Be aware!

Comment: bit more feedback re "nullptr" . This is a C++11 thing so it's not supported by the Embarcadero classic compiler. You'd have to run the Clang compiler to use this so I will be changing these back to NULL until I can complete the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop code is fine (though coded oddly, and inefficiently).

Chances are, you are invoking *undefined/illegal behavior* elsewhere in the code, and that is likely affecting the `while` loop as a *side effect*.

For instance, DO NOT use `malloc()`/`free()` in C++, use `new`/`delete` instead.  Your `TDoubleLinkedList` struct contains a `Name` member that is clearly a non-POD class type, as it is being assigned a `UnicodeString` value.  That member's constructor will NOT be run when using `malloc()` to allocate the `TDoubleLinkedList` instance, thus invoking *undefined behavior* when the `Name` parameter is assigned to the `ReturnNode->Name` member.

That being said, you should get rid of `CreateNode()` entirely, and instead add a proper constructor to `TDoubleLinkedNode` itself, eg:

```cpp
struct TDoubleLinkedNode
{
    int ID;
    UnicodeString Name;
    TDoubleLinkedNode *ptr_PriorNode;
    TDoubleLinkedNode *ptr_NextNode;

    TDoubleLinkedNode(int id, UnicodeString name, TDoubleLinkedNode *priorNode = NULL, TDoubleLinkedNode *nextNode = NULL) :
        ID(id),
        Name(name),
        ptr_PriorNode(priorNode),
        ptr_NextNode(nextNode)
    {
    }
};
```

And then `Add_ToEnd()` can be simplified:

```cpp
void __fastcall TDoubleLinkedList::Add_ToEnd ( int ID,
                                               UnicodeString Name
                                             )
{
    TDoubleLinkedNode* newNode = new TDoubleLinkedNode(ID, Name);
    if (!FHeadNode)
    {
        // Head Pointer has not been initialised. Set as newNode
        FHeadNode = newNode;
        return;
    }

    TDoubleLinkedNode* tempNode = FHeadNode;
    while (tempNode->ptr_NextNode) {
        tempNode = tempNode->ptr_NextNode;    // Move to the "Next" record
    }

    tempNode->ptr_NextNode = newNode;
    newNode->ptr_PriorNode = tempNode;
}
```

Which can actually be simplified much further:

```cpp
void __fastcall TDoubleLinkedList::Add_ToEnd ( int ID,
                                               UnicodeString Name
                                             )
{
    TDoubleLinkedNode** tempNode = &FHeadNode;
    while (*tempNode) {
        tempNode = &((*tempNode)->ptr_NextNode);
    }
    *tempNode = new TDoubleLinkedNode(ID, Name, *tempNode);
}
```

And more so if you add a `FTailNode` member to your class:

```cpp
void __fastcall TDoubleLinkedList::Add_ToEnd ( int ID,
                                               UnicodeString Name
                                             )
{
    TDoubleLinkedNode **tempNode = (FTailNode) ? &(FTailNode->ptr_NextNode) : &FHeadNode;
    FTailNode = new TDoubleLinkedNode(ID, Name, FTailNode);
    *tempNode = FTailNode;
}
```

---

That being said, a better solution is to not create a linked list manually at all.  Use the standard [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) container in the `<list>` header, eg:

```cpp
#include <list>

struct TNodeData
{
    int ID;
    UnicodeString Name;
};

class TDoubleLinkedList
{
private:
    std::list<TNodeData> FData;
public:
    ...
    void __fastcall Add_ToEnd(int ID, UnicodeString Name);
    ...
};

void __fastcall TDoubleLinkedList::Add_ToEnd ( int ID,
                                               UnicodeString Name
                                             )
{
    FData.push_back(TNodeData{ID, Name});
}
```

Comment: While I am grateful to *everyone* who has responded I kind of want to take this opportunity to say thank you for all the thousands of answers you've provided other people. It's probably inappropriate (singling you out).. but I can't count the number of times you have supplied the answers I needed over the years (supplied to others).

- I will look at std::list
- you've just blown my mind with pointers to pointers so I will look at that too.
- can't say this enough. thanks ->everyone<-

Comment: I've just noticed what you did with the variable defaults (pointers) on the TDoubleLinkedNode constructor. That's getting used straight away! I will persevere with the manual linked list as a "learning experience" and switch to std::list when I'm done. Thanks